# Asp:Calendar always return default date instead of user selected one after button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

I have an asp:Calendar like below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server" AutoPostback="false" SelectionMode="Day" Font-Size="10pt" BorderColor="White" BackColor="White" OnSelectionChanged="DateChange_UploadAllowedFrom"
                                            Width="216px" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Verdana" Height="188px" BorderWidth="1px" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth">
                                            <SelectedDayStyle Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="black" BackColor="#ffe9e9"></SelectedDayStyle>
                                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="White"></OtherMonthDayStyle>
                                            <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom"></NextPrevStyle>
                                            <DayHeaderStyle Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True"></DayHeaderStyle>
                                            <TitleStyle Font-Size="10pt" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333399"
                                                BackColor="#ffe9e9"></TitleStyle>
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The method in C# below works when a date is selected by user.

```
protected void DateChange_UploadAllowedFrom(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hdnAllowedFrom.Value = Session["UploadAllowedFrom"].ToString();
        }
```

When I debug the code, I actually see the value of hiddenfield is set to the selected value.

When the button below is pressed right after:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAllowedFrom" runat="server" Value="08/08/2018 12:00:00" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges"  runat="server" Width="120px" Height="50px" Text="Save Dates" OnClientClick="return false;"/>
```

The value of hiddenField is always coming as the default one: 08/08/2018 12:00:00

Please note that the page_load function is not working after I press the button, page is not being refreshed. I tried to use Session object, did not help. What might be the reason is it happening and how I can fix it? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Think you want `AutoPostback="true"`

Comment: You have the event click for btnSaveChanges?